# Find multiple cells with the same value in col A then search col C for a particular number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have multiple cells in column A with the same value (e.g the number 22). I want to identify those rows then search for the existence of a particular number in column B (e.g. the number 10); however, I only want to search for the existence of the number 10 in any row that has previously been identified as being a multiple from column A.

Comment: For the "successes" in column A, are you meaning you want to identify ONLY when it's 22, or all cells which have more than one instance? I'm guessing you're looking for the former, but please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your data range goes from A2:B100, with headers in A1:B1. Assuming you only want to identify what column A cells contain a single value, 22, you would build two columns. One to identify the successes in column A, and one to identify the successes of column A and column B. You could also do this in a single column if you like.

Column C will identify which cells have 22. The formula that you would put into C2 (and fill down) would be:

```
=(A2=22)
```

This would return true if the value in column A matched your value.

Then, in column D, you'd test if both the column C returned true, as well as if column B had your value, in this case we're testing for 10. The column D2 formula would be:

```
=AND(C2,B2=10)
```

All values in column D that returned TRUE would be what you're looking for.